# Android constraint layout textview to wrap context and show ellipse if no more space

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I want to use a constraint layout that will be able to satisfy

(1) wrap the content of 2nd TextView
[image]

(2) extend the width of the 2nd TextView until it shows ellipses when there are no more spaces.
[image]

All these 3 TextViews are on the same line and the background colours are much needed.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="Text View 1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="fill"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="Short Text "
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/text1"
        
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/text1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/text1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="Text View 3"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/text1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/text1" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Constrain the middle text view to the last and use `layout_constrainedWidth="true"` with the width set to `wrap_content` instead of `0dp`, as well as setting `layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"` so it aligns to the first view.

[Short text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRa4S.png), [Long text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xP4Zc.png)

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:text="Text View 1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:text="Short text"
    app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/text1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/text3"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/text1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/text1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:text="Text View 3"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/text1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/text1" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" is also important to mention

Comment: That's true, I forgot to mention it. I'll edit it into my answer